# How to prepare 2 row, 5 column grid to plot 10 boxplot in one figure using seaborn or matplotlib library?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a 10box plot in one image, in two rows, with the given code but no success, how can I implement this idea.

```
fig, axes =plt.subplots(2,5)
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

for i,t in enumerate(new_fs):
    df = pd.read_csv(t,sep='\t')

    sns.boxplot(data=df,  orient='v',ax=axes[i % 2] )
```

Thank you.

Comment: Incomplete code, unexplained problem, no mention of what "but no success" means. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the `ax` argument of `boxplot` requires a single axes. Not an array of axes.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for `plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots):

> for NxM, subplots with N>1 and M>1 are returned as a 2D array.

Therefore, your variable `axes` is a 2D array, you need to access the individual axes using `axes[i,j]`.

Alternatively, I would rewrite your for loop like so:

```
for t,ax in zip(new_fs, axes.flat):
    df = pd.read_csv(t,sep='\t')
    sns.boxplot(data=df, orient='v', ax=ax)
```